# HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST signify?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

What does `SC_BAD_REQUEST` signify? And when should be set `statusCode` of `HttpServletResponse` to `SC_BAD_REQUEST`?

It will be better if somebody provides the list and functionality of each `statusCode` and when it should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html):

> [`SC_BAD_REQUEST`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#SC_BAD_REQUEST)
>
> Status code (400) indicating the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As the name says, that Error Code indicates that the Request was in not in the format expected by the server. It's used a lot in RESTFul Services when -for example- the parameters sent are incomplete or inconsistent.